# Vite build: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, material-ui, vite

I imported this component from material-ui :
`import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';`

When i run **npm run build** then **npm run preview** i got this error in the console :
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')**.

This is the example [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/2164br?file=/demo.tsx) i use it.

Note: when i run the app with **npm run dev** it works fine.

Comment: Please include the relevant component code as well. Also, when you try to run in local, do you get any error?

Comment: when i run in local (npm run dev), it works fine

Comment: I think that the problem is coming from all components imported from "@mui/material/..."

Comment: So here is that same project, ported to `vite` in stackblitz. If you `npm run build` then `npm run preview`, it works just fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tqykvw?file=src/demo.tsx

Comment: but in my local machine it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that including `@mui/material` in **vite.config.js** and destructuring `Paper` from **@mui/material** will solve my issue.

in **vite.config.js**:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  //...
  optimizeDeps: {
  //... 
  include: [
    "@mui/material"
    // include other packages that may broke the build
  ]
 }
});
```

in the **component**:

`import {Paper, otherComponents...} from '@mui/material'`

Comment: Where did you add this in the vite config? Include isn't a valid property